# Checking record owner before editing in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

I’m learning Django, but it’s hanging on such a seemingly simple moment. I need to check and allow the user to edit only his posts, and if he clicks the link for editing someone else’s - render a specific page.

I can not form a condition for user verification, please help:

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def blogs_edit_text_post(request, post_id):
    post_form = PostForm(instance=TextPost.objects.get(id=post_id))
    owner = TextPost.objects.get(pk=1)

    if request.user == owner:
        if request.method == "POST":
            post_form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=TextPost.objects.get(id=post_id))

            if post_form.is_valid():
                post = post_form.save()
                return redirect(blogs_blog)

        return render(request, 'blogs/edit_text_post.html', {
            'post_form': post_form
        })
    else:
        return render(request, 'blogs/error_page.html', {})
```

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile_user_id')
    blog_title = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name='Название блога')
    blog_description = models.TextField(max_length=500, verbose_name='Пара слов о себе', blank=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(default='nophoto.jpg', upload_to='user_pics/', blank=True, verbose_name='Аватар')


class TextPost(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name='Заголовок')
    post = models.TextField(max_length=500, verbose_name='Текст поста', blank=False)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

**urls.py**

```
path('blogs/blog/', views.blogs_blog, name='blogs-blog')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note these points:

1. Don't relate TextPost to Profile model, relate it directly to the User model. It will be more easy for your project.
2. Always use "related_name" in OneToOneField or ForeignKeyField.
3. Always use context (or another named variable) to pass variable in template. in big projects, you will have to pass many variables.

**models.py**

```
class TextPost(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_name') # User, not Profiel, related_name added
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name='Заголовок')
    post = models.TextField(max_length=500, verbose_name='Текст поста', blank=False)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def blogs_edit_text_post(request, post_id):
    post = TextPost.objects.get(id=post_id)
    if post.author == request.user: # post.author.user == request.user if it's related to Profile 
        if request.method == "POST":
            post_form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=TextPost.objects.get(id=post_id))
            if post_form.is_valid():
                post = post_form.save()
                return redirect(blogs_blog)
        else:
            post_form = PostForm(instance=TextPost.objects.get(id=post_id))
        context = {
            'post_form': post_form
        }
        return render(request, 'blogs/edit_text_post.html', context)
    else:
        return render(request, 'blogs/error_page.html', {})
```